# I am the first in Earth, What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am the first in Earth,
>   The second in Heaven.
>
> I appear twice in a week,
>   Never in a month,
>   Once in a year.
>
> And I am found in the middle of the sea.

**What am I?**

Comment: This is a claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassic...

Comment: no, its trivial.

Comment: Time-tested formula, some problem solving and potentially unknown approach to solving. A good, if simple bit of puzzle creation. Well done.

Comment: Should it be fixed to 'first in Earth'?

Comment: You should cite your source for this puzzle.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**What am I?**

> The letter "E"

I am the first on Earth,

> E-arth

The second in Heaven.

> h-E-aven

I appear twice in a week,

> w-EE-k

Never in a month,

> month <--- no E!

Once in a year,

> y-E-ar

And I am found in the middle of the sea.

> s-E-a