# What is it that repeats once every minute?

Tags: riddle

This is my first riddle. Hope you enjoy it.

> What is it that
>   Repeats once every minute,
>   Repeats twice each moment,
>   But never in a hundred years?

What am I?

Comment: Your linkedin link is not linked to linkedin mate

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is not a logic puzzle - please check the tag wikis before using any tags.

Comment: To add to Bonjovi♦'s comment: usually people downvote riddles in a form like yours is at the moment. I'll edit it so people can see behind form ;)

Comment: Thanks for edit @Avigrail and I think my linkedin profile is well linked. Which is the problem, it doesn't appear to you?

Comment: @MateoHermosilla Now there it is :)

Comment: @Avigrail a nice tongue twister ;)

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/13339

Comment: That riddle appears on page 58 of [Howard's Book of Conundrums and Riddles](https://books.google.com/books?id=zLcEQQAACAAJ), copyright 1869.  So it's significantly more than 100 years old!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is

> M

Because

> **M** comes once in every **m**inute, twice in each **m**o**m**ent and never in a hundred years

Comment: Many would downvote the riddle because it is so short but as we can see it has a very clever solution! Well done

Comment: The wording in your answer is how the question should have been phrased. The letter M does not repeat once in the word minute, it repeats zero times.